# How to refactor a functioning piece of code written in jQuery/Coffeescript for reusability

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

The following code works for me:

```
  $ ->
    $("[id$=\"_phase_id\"]").change(->
      common_prefix = "type_well_type_well_phases_attributes_"
      cell_pos = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/g)
      mult = "#" + common_prefix + cell_pos + "_multiplier"
      mol  = $("#" + common_prefix + cell_pos + "_mol_percent").val()
      gpm  = "#" + common_prefix + cell_pos + "_GPM"
      component_id = $(this).val()
      $.getJSON('/phases/' + component_id, (data) ->
        pressure_base = 0.0
        if $("#type_well_pressure_base").val() == "14.65"
          pressure_base = data.base1
        else if $("#type_well_pressure_base").val() == "14.696"
          pressure_base = data.base2
        else if $("#type_well_pressure_base").val() == "14.73"
          pressure_base = data.base3
        else if $("#type_well_pressure_base").val() == "15.025"
          pressure_base = data.base4
        mult_value = parseFloat(pressure_base)
        $(mult).val mult_value
        $(gpm).val bcr_round_to(mult_value * (mol / 100.0), 4) if (mol != "")
      )
    ).trigger "change"
```

This is walking through a nested form (phase_attributes) in my Rails code to call json based on a value (presure_base drop-down) selected in my parent form (type_well) and then compute a value (gpm) for the nested form.  As you can see, if the phase is "changed" in the phases drop-down, I fetch the corresponding row from database and based on the value of pressure_base (14.65, 14.696, 14.73, 15.025), I compute the "gpm" value.  It is all working.

Now I am trying to put it the functionality to automatically recompute the nested form's "gpm" values when the "pressure_base" itself is changed by the user.  Clearly, I have to loop through the nested rows (I know how to do it so that is no problem), and basically repeat the process again for each nested row.  The only variable here is the "cell_pos".  Is there any way that I can extract out a subordinate jQuery/Coffeescript function which is called from my loop repeatedly?  I know how to do it in Ruby/Rails since I am quite comfortable with it, but have less experience with jQuery (even less with Coffeescript).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you should use the `change` event on `#type_well_pressure_base` to recalculate `gpm` value. Then you can use the getJSON callback just to change the stored values and trigger the computation.

```
phase = $('[id$="_phase_id"]')
phase.change ->
    self = $(this)
    common_prefix = "type_well_type_well_phases_attributes_"

    cell_pos = self.attr('id').match(/\d+/g)
    component_id = self.val()

    cell = "##{common_prefix}#{cell_pos}"
    mult = "#{cell}_multiplier"
    gpm  = "#{cell}_GPM"

    mol  = $("#{cell}_mol_percent").val()

    $.getJSON("/phases/#{component_id}", (data) ->
        pressure.base.data 'pb_data', data
        pressure_base.trigger 'change'

base_values =
    '14.65'  : 'base1'
    '14.696' : 'base2'
    '14.73'  : 'base3'
    '15.025' : 'base4'

pressure_base = $('#type_well_pressure_base')
pressure_base.change ->
    data = $(this).data 'pb_data'
    type_well_pb = pressure_base.val()
    base = base_values[type_well_pb]
    mult_value = parseFloat(data[base])
    $(mult).val mult_value
    $(gpm).val bcr_round_to(mult_value * (mol / 100.0), 4) if (mol != "")

phase.trigger 'change'
```